# VB Password Checker

Tags: vb.net

I have to check if a password meets safety requirements. I have to:

- Check that the length is at least 8 characters
- Check that there is at least one digit
- Check that there is at least one lower case character
- Check that there is at least one upper case character

This is the code I have so far

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the password checker")
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an 8 digit password")
        Dim mypassword As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Your password is, {0}", mypassword)
    End Sub

    Function Passwordlength(ByVal mypassword)
        mypassword.length()
        Console.WriteLine(mypassword.length)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05h65z0.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function returns `False` if the string is shorter than 8 characters. It then uses the `Any` method to check all the characters in the string to see if any of them are of a particular type. If there are no digits, lower case letters, or upper case letters, it returns `False`. If all those checks are passed, it returns `True`.

```
Function ValidPassword(myPassword As String) As Boolean
    If myPassword.Length < 8 Then Return False
    If Not myPassword.Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)) Then Return False
    If Not myPassword.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c)) Then Return False
    If Not myPassword.Any(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c)) Then Return False
    Return True
End Function
```

You can call the function like this

```
Dim myPassword As String = Console.ReadLine()
If ValidPassword(myPassword) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Your password is, {0}", mypassword)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Password {0} is invalid", mypassword)
End If
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Function longEnough(strdata As String) As Boolean
    If Len(strdata) > 7 Then
        Return True
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
Function HasNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
    Dim iCnt As Integer

    For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
            HasNumber = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iCnt

End Function

Function IsUpper(strData As String) As Boolean
    Dim iCnt As Integer

    For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
        If Char.IsUpper(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
            IsUpper = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iCnt

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim string1 As String = "hellothere"

        If longEnough(string1) = True And HasNumber(string1) = True And IsUpper(string1) = True Then
            MsgBox("you are good")
        Else
            MsgBox("you need a cap, upper, and be at least 8 characters")
        End If
```

Comment: you dont need that awful VB Mid function.  `strData(n)` will work fine because a string is a char array.  And the `Char` type already has `IsDigit` and IsUpper`  (not my DV)